# Avoid cannot read property of ... undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this function to append a title attr to every `tr` of my table. The content for the table is coming from an array. That works fine. But I also have a function with adds manually rows to the table. For these rows, I get an exception. Pretty clear, because they are not in the array. But how can I avoid these exceptions? I don't need to add titles to these rows.

it says:

> Cannot read property 'dictCanon' of undefined(…)

```
function postBody() {
    // add title to tr
    var trs = $table.find('tbody').children();
    for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
        $(trs[i]).mouseover(function(e) {
            index = $(e.currentTarget).data('index');
            var d = (diagnosis[index].additionalParameters);
            console.log('d', d);
            dt = $(e.currentTarget).parent().parent().find('thead').find('th')
                                   .eq($(e.currentTarget).data('index')).data();
            //console.log(dictCanon);
            if (d != undefined || d !== 'null') {
                 var dictCanon = diagnosis[index].additionalParameters.dictCanon;
                 var icd = diagnosis[index].additionalParameters.icd;
                 $(this).attr('title',icd + ' ' + dictCanon);
             }
        });                
    };
};
```

Comment: Could you post the error message? Often times it will say "Cannot read property <something> of undefined" and this can be helpful when trying to figure out where exactly the error occurred. Or you could check the line number, and tell us what line to look at.

Comment: What is `diagnosis`? It's not defined. Also `index`

Comment: @Michelem, `index` is retrieved in the event handler, and would correspond to the value of `i` at the time the event handler is created.

Comment: it says ' Cannot read property 'dictCanon' of undefined(…)'

Comment: Well, that means your array is large enough, but not all entries have the `additionalParameters` property. So please show how you manage the `diagnosis` array.

Comment: `if (d.hasOwnProperty('dictCanon') && (d != undefined || d !== 'null')) {`

Comment: I get it from an array (local storage) var data = JSON.parse(retrievedAnnotation);  function getDataN(code) {
    return data.annotationDtos
        .filter((data) => data.type === code); 
  };

Comment: @Jai, now I get Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error *"cannot read property 'dictCanon' of undefined"* is triggered on this expression:

```
diagnosis[index].additionalParameters.dictCanon
```

...which means you have entries in `diagnosis` that have no `additionalParameters` property. You tried to protect the code against that error, but did it with the wrong boolean operator. Use `&&` instead of `||` and don't put `null` in quotes. I would also suggest to adapt the condition in your `for` loop to make sure you have the necessary entry in `diagnosis`:

```
function postBody() {
    // add title to tr
    var trs = $table.find('tbody').children();
    for (var i = 0; i < trs.length && i < diagnosis.length; i++) {
        $(trs[i]).mouseover(function(e) {
            var index = $(e.currentTarget).data('index'); // use `var`
            var d = diagnosis[index].additionalParameters // parentheses not needed
            console.log('d', d);
            dt = $(e.currentTarget).parent().parent().find('thead').find('th')
                                   .eq(index).data(); // you have `index`, use it
            //console.log(dictCanon);
            if (d !== undefined && d !== null) { // <--- changed!
                 var dictCanon = d.dictCanon; // <-- you have `d`, use it
                 var icd = d.icd; // <-- idem
                 $(this).attr('title',icd + ' ' + dictCanon);
             }
        });                
    };
};
```

Note also some other changes I made... see comments in code.

Comment: Thank you that rocks, you save my day!